# Unable to change refresh rate using xrandr (xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed)

Tags: archlinux, xrandr

**Hello! I'm using a laptop with Arch Linux**

I have been trying to change the refresh rate from my laptop (144 Hz to 60 Hz) using:

`xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60`

But when I run that, I get this:

`xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed`

I have already checked that said refresh rate is supported by my monitor:

```
xrandr -q

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384

eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm

1920x1080 144.00*+ 60.01 59.97 59.96 59.93

1680x1050 59.95 59.88

1400x1050 74.76 59.98

1600x900 59.99 59.94 59.95 59.82

1280x1024 85.02 75.02 60.02

1400x900 59.96 59.88

1280x960 85.00 60.00

1440x810 60.00 59.97

1368x768 59.88 59.85

1280x800 59.99 59.97 59.81 59.91

1152x864 75.00

1280x720 60.00 59.99 59.86 59.74

1024x768 85.00 75.05 60.04 85.00 75.03 70.07 60.00

1024x768i 86.96

960x720 85.00 75.00 60.00

928x696 75.00 60.05

896x672 75.05 60.01

1024x576 59.95 59.96 59.90 59.82

960x600 59.93 60.00

832x624 74.55

960x540 59.96 59.99 59.63 59.82

800x600 85.00 75.00 70.00 65.00 60.00 85.14 72.19 75.00 60.32 56.25

840x525 60.01 59.88

864x486 59.92 59.57

700x525 74.76 59.98

800x450 59.95 59.82

640x512 85.02 75.02 60.02

700x450 59.96 59.88

640x480 85.09 60.00 85.01 72.81 75.00 59.94

720x405 59.51 58.99

720x400 85.04

684x384 59.88 59.85

640x400 59.88 59.98 85.08

576x432 75.00

640x360 59.86 59.83 59.84 59.32

640x350 85.08

512x384 85.00 75.03 70.07 60.00

512x384i 87.06

512x288 60.00 59.92

416x312 74.66

480x270 59.63 59.82

400x300 85.27 72.19 75.12 60.32 56.34

432x243 59.92 59.57

320x240 85.18 72.81 75.00 60.05

360x202 59.51 59.13

360x200 85.04

320x200 85.27

320x180 59.84 59.32

320x175 85.27)
```

I even specified the crtc, but I keep getting the same (xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed) error

`xrandr --output eDP-1 --crtc 0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.00`

Even changing to a resolution that is not 1920x1080 gives me the same error, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `--mode 1920x1080 --rate 60.01`? It may not support 60 Hz flat

Comment: I tried that, but the  `xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed` error persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This morning, I updated all of my packets

```
pacman -Syu
```

Unexpectedly solving the error

Answer (score 0):

try this
`xrandr --output eDP-1 --rate 60.00 --mode 1920x1080`

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Nope, I keep getting the same `xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed`